# Using roberta model cannot define the model .compile or summary

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, bert-language-model, roberta-language-model

Using roberta model for sentiment analysis cannot define the model .compile or summary

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, RobertaForSequenceClassification
from transformers import  BertConfig
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
robertamodel = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('roberta-base',num_labels=7)
print('\nBert Model',robertamodel.summary())
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('0accuracy')
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5,epsilon=1e-08)

robertamodel.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=[metric])
print(robertamodel.summary())
```

i got these errors
'RobertaForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'summary'
'RobertaForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: Are you sure this transformers library is using Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roberta is based on pytorch. Check out the helper function [TFRobertaModel](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html) to convert it to a tensorflow model.