# 'DebertaV2ForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, pre-trained-model, huggingface-tokenizers, fine-tuning

I am running below code :

```
mod_nm= "MoritzLaurer/mDeBERTa-v3-base-xnli-multilingual-nli-2mil7"
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(mod_nm, num_labels=8, ignore_mismatched_sizes=True)
```

and i got this error

```
AttributeError: 'DebertaV2ForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'compile'`
```

I tried to change model still getting error.

Comment: Does [Using roberta model cannot define the model .compile or summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152276/using-roberta-model-cannot-define-the-model-compile-or-summary) help?